# Why isn't my sort working in Perl?

Tags: perl, sorting, inheritance, methods, subroutine

I have never used Perl, but I need to complete this exercise. My task is to sort an array in a few different ways. I've been provided with a test script. This script puts together the array and prints statements for each stage of it's sorting. I've named it foo.pl:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use MyIxHash;

my %myhash;
my $t = tie(%myhash, "MyIxHash", 'a' => 1, 'abe' => 2, 'cat'=>'3');
$myhash{b} = 4;
$myhash{da} = 5;
$myhash{bob} = 6;

print join(", ", map { "$_ => $myhash{$_}" } keys %myhash) . " are the starting key => val pairs\n";

$t->SortByKey;  # sort alphabetically
print join(", ", map { "$_ => $myhash{$_}" } keys %myhash) . " are the alphabetized key => val pairs\n";

$t->SortKeyByFunc(sub {my ($a, $b) = @_; return ($b cmp $a)});  # sort alphabetically in reverse order
print join(", ", map { "$_ => $myhash{$_}" } keys %myhash) . " are the reverse alphabetized key => val pairs\n";

$t->SortKeyByFunc(\&abcByLength);  # use abcByLength to sort
print join(", ", map { "$_ => $myhash{$_}" } keys %myhash) . " are the abcByLength sorted key => val pairs\n";

print "Done\n\n";


sub abcByLength {
  my ($a, $b) = @_;

  if(length($a) == length($b)) { return $a cmp $b; }
  else { return length($a) <=> length($b) } 
}
```

Foo.pl uses a package called MyIxHash which I've created a module for called MyIxHash.pm. The script runs through the alphabetical sort: "SortByKey", which I've inherited via the "IxHash" package in my module. The last two sorts are the ones giving me issues. When the sub I've created: "SortKeyByFunc" is ran on the array, it passes in the array and a subroutine as arguments. I've attempted to take those arguments and associate them with variables.

The final sort is supposed to sort by string length, then alphabetically. A subroutine for this is provided at the bottom of foo.pl as "abcByLength". In the same way as the reverse alpha sort, this subroutine is being passed as a parameter to my SortKeyByFunc subroutine.

For both of these sorts, it seems the actual sorting work is done for me, and I just need to apply this subroutine to my array.

My main issue here seems to be that I don't know how, if possible, to take my subroutine argument and run my array through it as a parameter. I'm a running my method on my array incorrectly?

```
package MyIxHash;
#use strict;
use warnings;
use parent Tie::IxHash;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

sub SortKeyByFunc {
    #my $class = shift;
    my ($a, $b) = @_;

    #this is a reference to the already alphabetaized array being passed in
    my @letters = $_[0][1];

    #this is a reference to the sub being passed in as a parameter
    my $reverse = $_[1];

    #this is my variable to contain my reverse sorted array
    my @sorted = @letters->$reverse();

    return @sorted;
}

1;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "My problem occurs where I try: `my @sorted = @letters->$reverse();` I've also tried: `my @sorted = sort {$reverse} @letters;`"

You were really close; the correct syntax is:

```
my $reverse = sub { $b cmp $a };
# ...
my @sorted = sort $reverse @letters;
```

Also note that, for what are basically historical reasons, `sort` passes the arguments to the comparison function in the (slightly) magic globals `$a` and `$b`, not in `@_`, so you don't need to (and indeed shouldn't) do `my ($a, $b) = @_;` in your sortsubs (unless you declare them with a prototype; see [perldoc -f sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) for the gritty details).

---

**Edit:** If you're given a comparison function that for some reason *does* expect its arguments in `@_`, and you can't change the definition of that function, then your best bet is probably to wrap it in a closure like this:

```
my $fixed_sortsub = sub { $weird_sortsub->($a, $b) };

my @sorted = sort $fixed_sortsub @letters;
```

or simply:

```
my @sorted = sort { $weird_sortsub->($a, $b) } @letters;
```

---

**Edit 2:** Ah, I see the/a problem.  When you write:

```
my @letters = $_[0][1];
```

what you end up with a is a single-element array containing whatever `$_[0][1]` is, which is presumably an [array reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).  You should either dereference it immediately, like this:

```
my @letters = @{ $_[0][1] };
```

or just keep is as a reference for now and dereference it when you use it:

```
my $letters = $_[0][1];
# ...
my @sorted = sort $whatever @$letters;
```

---

**Edit 3:**  Once you do manage to sort the keys, then, as duskwuff notes in his original answer, you'll also need to call the `Reorder()` method from your parent class, [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Tie%3a%3aIxHash) to actually change the order of the keys.  Also, the first line:

```
my ($a, $b) = @_;
```

is completely out of place in what's supposed to be an object method that takes a code reference (and, in fact, lexicalizing `$a` and `$b` is a bad idea anyway if you want to call `sort` later in the same code block).  What it should read is something like:

```
my ($self, $sortfunc) = @_;
```

In fact, rather than enumerating all the things that seem to be wrong with your original code, it might be easier to just fix it:

```
package MyIxHash;
use strict;
use warnings;
use parent 'Tie::IxHash';

sub SortKeyByFunc {
    my ($self, $sortfunc) = @_;

    my @unsorted = $self->Keys();

    my @sorted = sort { $sortfunc->($a, $b) } @unsorted;

    $self->Reorder( @sorted );
}

1;
```

or simply:

```
sub SortKeyByFunc {
    my ($self, $sortfunc) = @_;

    $self->Reorder( sort { $sortfunc->($a, $b) } $self->Keys() );
}
```

(Ps. I now see why the comparison functions were specified as taking their arguments in `@_` rather than in the globals `$a` and `$b` where `sort` normally puts them: it's because the comparison functions belong to a different package, and `$a` and `$b` are *not* magical enough to be the same in every package like, say, `$_` and `@_` are.  I guess that *could* be worked around, but it would take some quite non-trivial trickery with `caller`.)

(Pps. Please do credit me and duskwuff / Stack Overflow when you hand in your exercise.  And good luck with learning Perl — trust me, it'll be a useful skill to have.)

Comment: @user1361666: No problem. If you've found an answer (this or any other) that solves your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking the check mark icon to the left of it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

The code you provided isn't throwing any errors, but it also isn't sorting my array. 

When you mention the $a and $b variables are you referring to the line
`my ($a, $b) = @_;`
in my SortKeyByFunc subroutine or the subroutine being passed in from foo.pl? I ask because foo.pl is script that was provided for me and shouldn't need to be altered.

This is being passed when they call my sub: 

`$t->SortKeyByFunc(sub {my ($a, $b) = @_; return ($b cmp $a)});`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, what you really should do is go to whoever wrote your `foo.pl` and ask them what the heck they were thinking. But if you really have to use an externally-provided comparison function that doesn't follow the usual calling convention used by `sort`, then your best bet is probably to write a wrapper for it; see my edit above.

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't my sort work if I write out a compare just to test like this:  
`my @sorted = sort {$b cmp $a} @letters;`

This doesn't even work. I think my @letters array is fine.. when I dump it I get: `$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'abe',
          'b',
          'bob',
          'cat',
          'da'
        ];`

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to do the trick. The only difference is when I dump my array I now get variables for each element like:

`$VAR1 = 'da';
$VAR2 = 'cat';
$VAR3 = 'bob';
$VAR4 = 'b';
$VAR5 = 'abe';
$VAR6 = 'a';`

Before when I would dump my array I'd get something like `$VAR1 = [
          'a',
          'abe',
          'b',
          'bob',
          'cat',
          'da'
        ];`

How are these different? Also, @duskwuff mentioned in his response I need to use "Reorder" to replace my current array in $t, but this doesn't seem to do anything, and I can't find any info on reorder()

Comment: That's because when you call `Dumper(@foo)` it'll dump each of the elements of `@foo` separately; see [perldoc Data::Dumper](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Data::Dumper) for details. As for `Reorder()`, that's a method from [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Tie::IxHash), your parent class, and you should see its documentation for what it does.

Answer (score 4):

Your `SortKeyByFunc` method returns the results of sorting the array (`@sorted`), but it doesn't modify the array "in place". As a result, just calling `$t->SortKeyByFunc(...);` doesn't end up having any visible permanent effects.

You'll need to call `$t->Reorder()` within your `SortKeyByFunc` method to have any lasting impact on the array. I haven't tried it, but something like:

```
$t->Reorder(@sorted);
```

at the end of your method may be sufficient.

Comment: The array in `@sorted` isn't the correct, sorted array yet. My problem occurs where I try:

`my @sorted = @letters->$reverse();`

I've also tried:

`my @sorted = sort {$reverse} @letters;`